# How to browse elements and view their properties?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

They have deprecated the properties panel in Chrome. Now, instead of clicking once to view properties I must change to the console, type console.dir($0) and enter! If I want to view the properties for the following tag, I must go back to "elements", select, then back to console...

Then when you do find the property list you want it is now horizontally oriented rather than vertical, so more scrolling is required. Or you switch to full console and lose the elements panel. I keep looking at all that wasted space on the right and fume.

This is so counter-productive, that I assume there is some other way to browse properties of elements. But I cannot find it.

Is there an efficient way to browse elements and view their properties in Chrome dev-tools?

Comment: As usual they "know better" what users need, but they may relent when a decent amount of time passes (a year maybe) so their decisions don't look hasty (which they definitely seem to be) and unprofessional. See also https://crbug.com/1082802. Meanwhile someone can write a custom extension for that...

Comment: @wOxxOm I see someone at Chrome who actually uses Chrome Dev Tools, has complained, and it has been fixed. Amazing fast when one of their own has issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to post an answer to this question summing up what happened (as this version of Chrome is still embedded in the latest Electron so is relevant):

This was [deprecated in Chrome 84](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/devtools#properties) and [reinstated in Chrome 86](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/08/devtools#properties).

There was a [user submitted bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1082802) where they were chastised for "unhelpful comments" in suggesting that there was a regression. Followed by an almost identical [Google employee bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1116085) which was promptly fixed...